# How can I fix this Samba setup on CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, samba, centos6, server-message-block

I'm trying to set a Samba share in /home/share on CentOS. I do not have great experience with setting up that kind of service. I've been following guides and recommendations here and there, but there's still something missing. Here's the full problem description.

**Machine setup:** I'm running in VMware player (hopefully ESX soon) a CentOS 6.3 server installed using the "minimal" ISO image. Bridged networking.

**What I'm trying to do:** Setup a Samba share folder for some users on the network to access (Windows users).

**Symptoms:** I can't connect to the share, nor can I get a list of shares at all. I tried from my Mint 14 laptop, and from a Win7 computer. I can ping the VM, but I can't get it to connect to the shared directory. I tried all ways I could think of. I frequently mount remote directories both on Windows and Linux. I'm pretty sure something's missing in my configurations.

**What I have done so far:**

- Fixed network access by following the indications [here](http://www.convirture.com/ee_wiki/index.php?title=RedHat_6_Networking) ("For DHCP" section). I couldn't ping anything before doing this. Now I can ping other computers on the local network, and popular domains on the Internet.
- Installed MySQL ODBC connector (yum), Mono (compiled), and Samba (yum). I need the first two for something else. Just saying for the sake of completeness.
- Added firewall rules for samba according to [this page](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba). I verified syntax (testparm) and it also loads without any error. iptables:

> ```
> *filter
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
> :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
> :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
> -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
> -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
>
> -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
>
> COMMIT
> ```

- I threw in `setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs on` and tried to `semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t '/home/share(/.*)?'` but it looks like semanage is not installed. Anyway, [like they say](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba#head-86233024cba06a1e4f554e763a2f634a61eae9b8), I'd have an empty share. Now I don't have any share at all.
- Here's my Samba conf file so far:

> ```
> [global]
>   workgroup = WORKGROUP
>   server string = Samba Server
>   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
>   max log size = 50
>   security = user
>   passdb backend = tdbsam
>   load printers = yes
>   cups options = raw
>
> [files]
>   comment = File directory
>   path = /home/share
>   valid users = user1
>   public = no
>   writable = yes
>   printable = no
>   create mask = 0765
> ```

- Other than that, I created a user on CentOS, and gave him access to the share, by listing them in the samba conf file (user1 above) and by running `smbpasswd -a user1`.
- I thought the problem could be /home/share permissions, so I set user1 as owner of /home/share.
- I manually make sure that smbd (and nmbd) service is running.

That must be exactly everything I did since OS installation (excluding Mono build details).

**I'm totally stuck. I'm reading other guides and trying random configs here and there, but I'm clueless. Any help will be much appreciated.**

**EDIT:**
For the record, what was missing (for permissions):

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t '/home/share(/.*)?'
restorecon -R /home/share
```

Comment: Check the log files in `/var/log/samba` for clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With iptables, the rules are applied in the order they are written. The rules that come after

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

will never be processed as it is a blanket reject. Put these

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
```

before it.

Comment: Have to wait before accepting the answer... That fixed it. I still have permission problems, but that I should be able to figure out.